# Is the SimH emulator available on macOS?

Tags: unix, pdp-11, simh

Is the SimH emulator available for macOS? I can't find it on their website: http://simh.trailing-edge.com/

What I am specifically interested in is to run UNIX V7 on a PDP-11 emulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s available in [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) for macOS; install that, then

```
brew install simh
```

to install SimH.

Answer (score 1):

What [homebrew](http://homebrew.sh) will install for you on MacOS as of today (Aug. 30 2017) is simh V3.9, which does look to be the latest non-beta release at present.

A beta release of simh V4.0 is available that is also supported on current and recent versions of MacOS. You can find it at https://github.com/simh/simh if you're interested. V4.0 introduces support for emulating quite a few new processors and variants of already supported processors, as well as many enhancements to simh itself.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Thanks for the answer. It would be useful if you could [edit](/posts/4612/edit) it so that it contains enough information to answer the specific question "Is the SimH emulator available _on macOS_?" - at present it doesn't give this information.

Answer (score 1):

You can also install `simh` from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org); to install it do:

```
port install simh
```

As the time of this writing, MacPorts is installing `simh` V3.8-1.

I am also adding how to run Unix System 7, as I found a couple of inconsistencies in the original instructions:

Now for putting it to work with Unix system7, download the PDP 11 Unix 7 tape image from  http://simh.trailing-edge.com/kits/uv7swre.zip

Then unzip either double-clicking on it, or with ´unzip` from MacPorts:

```
unzip uv7swre.zip
```

If you have now new subdirectories, go inside them until finding the `unix_v7_rl.dsk` file. Put it in a directory of your convenience.

To boot then it, use the `simh-pdp11` as it is que equipment you need to emulate to run your image:

```
$ simh-pdp11
PDP-11 simulator V3.8-1
sim> set cpu 11/45
Disabling XQ
sim> set tto 7b   
sim> attach rl unix_v7_rl.dsk    
sim> boot rl
@boot
New Boot, known devices are hp ht rk rl rp tm vt 
: rl(0,0)rl2unix
mem = 177856
```

If it is the first time booting the image, create the missing directories of Dennis Ritchie´s user home, and `/tmp`:

```
# mkdir /usr/dmr
# chown dmr /usr/dmr
# chgrp 3 /usr/dmr
# mkdir /tmp
# chmod 777 /tmp
```

Then press `^D` to proceed:

```
# Restricted rights: Use, duplication, or disclosure
is subject to restrictions stated in your contract with
Western Electric Company, Inc.
Thu Sep 22 05:48:15 EDT 1988

login: dmr
$
```

The `dmr` user has no password by default.

If you need to login as root, by default, in this tape image, the `root` account has as password, `root`.

For leaving the emulation:

```
$ sync
$ sync
$ ^E
Simulation stopped, PC: 002306 (MOV (SP)+,177776)
sim> quit
Goodbye
```

Comment: I ran through the instructions and I can confirm they work beautifully. Bit of a shocker to see how little Unix v7 had. Not even vi.

Comment: @JeremyP While this tape image is very interesting historically, the PDP 11 tape of the sys V one is far more, having C sources. Will probably make a post detailing the installation in the next couple of days. I still have an improvement to make here today or tomorrow *if I find my old backups*, stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

However if you need network support install [Tunnelblick](https://tunnelblick.net)'s kernel extension. The config looks like this:

```
! kextload -v /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-notarized.kex
SET XQB ENABLED                                                                 
SET XQB MAC=08-00-2B-AA-BB-CE                                                   
SET XQB TYPE=DELQA-T                                                            
ATTACH XQB0 tap:tap0                                                            
! ifconfig tap0 192.168.11.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```